# Proper usage of util.promisify node js

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to use [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert [AWS Document client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) get function to a promise based utility. But it does not seem to behave as expected;

```
// This does not work as expected
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
let docClientGet = require('util').promisify(docClient.get);
```

However when i do usual promise conversion like this,

```
  let docClientGet = function (params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        return resolve(data);
      })
    })
  };
```

And use it in an async function like this:

```
await docClientGet(params);
```

It works!.

I wonder where I am wrong in understanding `util.promisify`

Comment: Please post more code, can you show the async function which you have written.

Comment: `docClient.get` probably needs `this` set to `docClient` so use `utils.promisify(docClient.get.bind(docClient));`

Comment: @RolandStarke that worked!! Thanks man. you can put that as the answer and I will accept with upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method you are promisifying needs to be associated with the object it is on (which it looks like it does in your case, then this code:

```
let docClientGet = utils.promisify(docClient.get);
```

will not retain the association with the `docClient` object.  What happens is that the promisified `docClient.get()` gets called without the `this` value set to the `docClient` object and it can't do its job properly.

You can work around that with this:

```
utils.promisify(docClient.get.bind(docClient));
```

The [promisify doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html) does not make this clear because it uses an example from the `fs` library whose methods do not need to be associated with the `fs` object in order to work properly.

P.S. It's a bit unusual to put the `util` library into a variable named `utils`.  That is likely to confuse some people reading your code.

Comment: Thanks! this is a lot clearer answer. Also edited the question and eliminated variable.